# Should I check for NULL pointer after malloc and calloc of 2D array in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-leaks, calloc, null-pointer

OK, I acknowledge that I should check for NULL pointer when mallocing, but what about calloc? Are there any memory leaks possible?

```
int **initializeMatrix(int *rows, int *cols) {
    int **matrix = malloc((*rows) * sizeof(int*));
    checkNullPointer(matrix);
    for(int i = 0; i < *rows; i++) {
        matrix[i] = calloc(*cols, sizeof(int));
    }

    return matrix;
}

void checkNullPointer(int **ptr) {
    if (ptr == NULL)
        printErrorMessage(memoryErrorMessage, 101);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it’s different with calloc?

Comment: Nobody talks about it. When you are callocing the memory, it is set to some value, while when mallocing the memory gets reserved for use isn't it?

Comment: checking the return value of `malloc` and related has nothing to do with memory leaks. You check the pointer it returns to see if the operation was successful or not.

Comment: `When you are callocing the memory is set to some value,` and where from calloc does magically take this memory for zeroing? calloc is just malloc + memset

Comment: OK, so the checking for NULL pointer is because when I'll be freeing the memory at the end of the code, I'll not free the NULL pointer which would lead into some serious issues, right?

Comment: @tomashauser: There's no need to free a NULL pointer since it doesn't point to anything.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour. Same as spending not your money. You can go to jail or even worse if it is the mafia money

Comment: If you didn't check for it, you wouldn't know that it's NULL and you'd free it as every other pointer, thus the error will occur.

Comment: @P__J__: U wot? `free(NULL)` has been defined as a no-op since ANSI C.

Comment: @Bathsheba - I wrote about using NULL pointer

Comment: Note that you are not allocating a 2-dimensional array.  You are allocating an array of pointers to multiple, completely separate 1-dimensionally arrays.  That's a highly inefficient way to allocate memory, especially for "arrays" with more than two dimensions.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: `calloc` [documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html).

Comment: `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` can all potentially return `NULL` if an allocation request cannot be satisfied, so yes, you should check the result of all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do indeed need to check the return value of `calloc` (it will be `NULL` if memory could not be allocated), but note that calling `free` on a `NULL` pointer is a no-op, so there is no immediate memory leak per se.

Of course, when cleaning up after encountering a `NULL` return, you'll need to call `free` on all non-`NULL` pointers emanating from successful `calloc` calls. Personally I'd call `calloc` on the row allocation too to make that process simpler.

Comment: So in every iteration, I should do `checkNullPointer(matrix[i]);`, is that right?

Comment: @tomashauser: Well, you'll need a version of that with the appropriate pointer type: your pointer will be an `int *` type, although to be honest you could rewrite it taking `void*`, so you can use it for both cases.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I'll just do `if (matrix[i] == NULL) {...}`.

Comment: @tomashauser: No, `free` contains that `if` statement implicitly.

Comment: What do you mean by that? `matrix[i]` is now a pointer which I am checking for being NULL. Next I'll free everything else but this pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not understand what the calloc is.

Logical equivalent:

```
void *mycalloc(size_t num, size_t size)
{
    size_t total = size * num;
    void *ptr = malloc(total);
    if(ptr)
    {
        memset(ptr, 0, total);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

You need to check if the memory was allocated exactly the same way as when usung malloc.

Comment: I haven't heard of memset. I just thought that calloc will do malloc and assign zeroes in the designated memory space. But I didn't know that the NULL pointer checking was for failing to allocate the memory which could happen as well when callocing.

Comment: Well I'm obviously learning C and there are things which I can't find anywhere or deduce myself, so I ask here. It's not like asking how calloc works. This is a concrete problem which I stumbled upon.

Comment: There's a typo in the return type of `mycalloc`. Obviously, it should return `void *`.